# Best way to create multiple .o

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I have 4 ".c" files in src/ , main1.c, main2.c, main3.c, main4.c. I want to create main1.o, main2.o, main3.o, main4.o respectively, in bin/ . I can write a makefile for this, but in a very newbish way. What might be the best way to write makefile for this problem. I want one single command. Right now I am doing the following.

```
all: src/main1.c src/main2.c
     gcc-Wall -fpic -c src/main1.c -o bin/main1.o
     gcc-Wall -fpic -c src/main2.c -o bin/main2.o
```

Comment: Perchance by "one single command" did you mean "one single *target*" ? Because if not, there are ample examples of how to setup multi-target make configurations in the [gnumake documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/).

Comment: ya i meant target

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In make, you want to define the *targets* you want to be created or brought up to date.  Here, your `all` target depends on the *source files*, which is wrong: you don't want make to create the source files.  The source files already exist.  You want make to create the object files, in the `bin` directory.

So, your `all` rule should be:

```
all: bin/main1.o bin/main2.o
```

Now, you have to teach make how to create a `bin/xxx.o` from a `src/xxx.c`.

You can do that by writing a [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html), which is a template that make can use to figure out how to build things.  For example:

```
bin/%.o : src/%.c
        gcc -Wall -fpic -c $< -o $@
```

The `$<` and `$@` are [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) that make will set for your recipe before trying to run it, for each target you want to build.

That's it!  See [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) for more information.

Comment: Put another way, when working with makefiles you don't think "here's what I start with, what do I do next?"  Instead you think, "here's where I want to end up, what's the step that gets me there?  Then what's the step before that?" etc. until you end up with no steps left (you've arrived at the start)